# Getting list of linked libraries form cocoa code

Tags: cocoa, get, linked-list, runtime, libraries

On my application starting I need to get list of libraries that are linked to it.
Unfortunately, I could't find any example in cocoa how can I do it from code. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Some of them causes crash of the app. So I need to change the app behavior depend on linked libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there's probably a better way than this (and this is completely untested written-into-this-text-field code), but I think this would do the trick:

```
uint32_t imageCount = _dyld_image_count();
char **names = calloc(sizeof(char *), imageCount);
int32_t *versions = calloc(sizeof(int32_t), imageCount);
for (uint32_t idx = 0; idx < imageCount; idx++) {
    names[idx] = _dyld_get_image_name(idx);
    versions[idx] = NSVersionOfLinkTimeLibrary(names[idx]);
}
```

If I'm understanding dyld.h properly, this should get you a list of all the currently loaded mach-o images and their *link-time* versions. Any mach-o image with a link-time version of -1 wasn't linked against from the main executable.